# Making Phone Calls from a Different Device

Tags: root-access, calls

Let's assume that I know my device will fall in the ocean in 6 months, I'm not allowed to buy insurance, and my contract expires in 18 months. I'm also a terrible swimmer, and Michael Phelps won't get it for me.

I would think that you could reverse engineer the code and make your own phone calls from a different device, even without the sim card. You just need to be able to program it.

I'm mostly curious if this has been done before and if it has a name. Are there any similar tricks/ideas?

Comment: My advice would be - take the easier route. Improve your dexterity and hold on to the phone.

Comment: I can't help it. I'm clumsy.

Comment: Sorry, this is off-topic because it has nothing to do with Android.

Answer (score 1):

If something like that should happen, you can just get your carrier to "port" your phone number to a new SIM card, and use that in the replacement/spare device. This is more or less the same process you use to transfer your number to a different carrier, but a lot simpler in this case. After all, they're the ones in control of what phone number goes with what SIM. Ask the carrier for a replacement SIM and they should be happy to oblige.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, though I was really trying to create a scenario in which I was forced to do it myself. I apparently failed :).

Comment: I believe that would be illegal. Isn't it akin to SIM cloning? It has various security threats and is illegal to prevent terrorism and loss of personal information or identity.

Comment: @AdityaSomani Yeah. There are definitely malicious uses for this information. Makes it hard to learn this area of computer science :/.

Comment: @MillieSmith That's why your question should tell us exactly what problem you're trying to solve. It's hard to answer a question when it requires a kind of guessing game about what the questioner is really trying to achieve.